# EF Core equivalent of ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

We previously (i.e., in EF 6) used the following code to obtain all enum properties which are used in any entity or complex type in our EF model:

```
var metadataWorkspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
var enumTypes = metadataWorkspace
                 .GetItems<StructuralType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
                 .SelectMany(t => t.Members)
                 .OfType<EdmProperty>()
                 .Where(m => m.EnumType != null)
                 .Select(m => m.EnumType)
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToList();
```

What is the EF Core equivalent of this? How to access "all types" in the model?

Is the following correct and *complete* (i.e., not missing owned types or anything like that).

```
var enumTypes = context.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                 .SelectMany(et => et.GetProperties())
                 .Where(p => p.ClrType.IsEnum)
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToList();
```